# Is there a way to OCR all pdf files within one folder using Python?

Tags: python

As the title states, is there a way to OCR all pdf files within one folder using Python? I have this code below, but it only OCR's one file at a time and extract text. I want to do a general OCR of all the pdf in a folder. Please let me know if its possible to do so.

```
from wand.image import Image
from PIL import Image as PI
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders
import io

tool = pyocr.get_available_tools()[0]
lang = tool.get_available_languages()[1]

req_image = []
final_text = []

image_pdf = Image(filename="./PDF_FILE_NAME", resolution=300)
image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')

for img in req_image: 
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(img)),
        lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the glob module.
You can match against a pattern for a given folder.
Here is your code with some edits to show how it might work.

```
import glob
pdfs = glob.glob("./*.pdf")

for pdf in pdfs:
    image_pdf = Image(pdf, resolution=300)
    image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')
    txt = tool.image_to_string(
        PI.open(io.BytesIO(image_jpeg)),
        lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
    )
    final_text.append(txt)
```

Comment: I am trying to import a pdf file and export out OCR'ed PDF file. Does the code output the OCRed pdf?